# Click tracking from a button in PHP using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

This is my Current JS For Saving Data using Ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/myPhpCode.php",
    data: "field1=" + field1 + "&field2=" + field2,
    success : function(text){
        if (text == "success"){
            functionForSucess();
        } else {
            functionForError();
        }
    }
});
```

Now I need an Ajax Code that will simply track a click from a Button (NOT "Submit") that will simply insert to the DB the User IP Address and Current Date (which are generated from the PHP file).

I can do the PHP Code, but dont know how to do the Ajax part. Im worried that the user will just simply typed-in my PHP File to the Address bar, and since I am NOT posting any user input, there is no way for the PHP to check if the user clicked on the button or just typed-in the PHP file in the browser address bar.

I want my Ajax click tracking code here

```
function showDiv(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    e.style.display = "block";
    $.ajax({
        // Ajax part here
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Token Generation:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $token = md5(rand(1000,9999)); //you can use any encryption
  $_SESSION['token'] = $token; //store it as session variable
?>
```

aJax:

```
        <?php session_start(); ?>
        var var1 = "whatever";
        var var2 = "whatever";
        var token = "<?php echo $_SESSION["token"]; ?>";
        var SendInfo= {     "var1": var1,
                            "var2": var2,
                            "token": token };

        $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'yoururl.php',
                data: SendInfo,
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
                traditional: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    // stuff here
                }
        });
```

Handler:

```
  session_start();
  if(@isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']=="http://yourdomain/ajaxurl") {
    //HTTP_REFERER verification
    if($_POST['token'] == $_SESSION['token']) {
      //do your ajax task
      //don't forget to use sql injection prevention here.
    }
  }
```

Note:  All of this information can be spoofed, with exception to the $_SESSION stuff, so store any variables you're concerned with a user manipulating in the SESSION object as using POST etc for security does not work in this instance if 
you're looking to prevent outside use of your software.  Doing it this way ensures a valid session object has been established (aka the user is logged in).

Comment: as I said I am not sending any data to PHP, The User IP and Date are generated inside the PHP File

Comment: You need to use tokens to validate then.  Sorry misread your question.

Comment: How can I use token, I am not using form. Its just a button (without form). Can you provide sample code

Answer (score 0):

> Once you have created the meta tag, you can instruct a library like
>   jQuery to add the token to all request headers. This provides simple,
>   convenient CSRF protection for your AJAX based applications:
>
> $.ajaxSetup({ headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN':
>   $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') } });

```
        $.ajaxSetup({
           headers:
               { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') }
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: "/your/url",
            method: "POST",
            data:
            {
                a: 'something',
                b: 'something else',
            },
            datatype: "json"
        });

        request.done(function(msg) {

        });

        request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {

        });
```

for the button if click

```
      $('#btnID').on('click',function(){
          ajax here
      });
```

Comment: What is the use of `data` here? I am not passing any value to my PHP, the USer IP and Date are generated inside my PHP file. My button is just a button without a form

Comment: just do like this data:{}

Comment: The user can just typed in the URL of the PHP file in the browser address bar, I need to know if the button was clicked or the URl was just typed in. With your code, how can my PHP know if the button was clicked or not?

Comment: Sorry, I still dont get it, how will my PHP know if the visit came from a button click or it was just typed from the address bar

Comment: for example if the visit came from a button then in that click event trigger the ajax and if typed in url just put ajax in document ready